# creating and editing a 2 dimensional mutable string array

Tags: string, cocoa, nsmutablestring

In my iOS app I want to populate an array initially with strings containing 13 spaces each. Then during processing in random order for each row of the array I want character-by-character to replace each space with a single character from the string "NESW", depending on how the process goes.

Is this the correct way to initialize the array? And is the next code line an example of how I will be able to replace the second space in the string in position [0][3] to be an "N"?

```
[deals[0][3] replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1) withString:@"N"];


NSString* spaces = @"             ";  // 13 spaces
+(NSMutableString* [2][4])deals{
    return (NSMutableString* [2][4]){
        {spaces,spaces,spaces,spaces},
    {spaces,spaces,spaces,spaces}

};
}
```

Comment: Try not to use c-styled array here. Use `NSArray *array=@[@[space, space, space, space], @[space, space, space, space]];` will prevent lots of memory issues.

Comment: Do I need to use `NSMutableString` for `spaces` or just `NSString` here. The docs seem to say I need `NSMutableString` to be able to replace a single character, because that feature is not available with just `NSString`. But I am having trouble initializing with `NSMutableString* spaces = @"             ";` getting the error "Incompatible pointer types" whether I include or exclude the '*'. What's up with this?

Comment: @"xxx" can only be initializer of NSString. `NSMutableString *spaces = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@" "];` can do.

Comment: If you're targeting (was it 10.7 or 10.8) recent OS versions only, you can still access NSArray members by C-style subscripting if you're more comfortable with that. E.g. `myArray[ someIndex ];`